Why is idToken nested under data instead of top-level when using @react-native-google-signin/google-signin?
I’m using @react-native-google-signin/google-signin in my React Native app (for Android and iOS), and the documentation states that when I call GoogleSignin.signIn(), the returned userInfo object should have idToken at the top level, like this:
const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
const { idToken } = userInfo; // Should work directly

However, when I log out userInfo, I’m seeing something like this:
{
  "data": {
    "idToken": "some_jwt_token_here",
    "user": { ...userData... },
    ...
  },
  "type": "success"
}

I’m concerned because this doesn’t match the official documentation, and I’m worried about future compatibility and maintainability. I haven’t intentionally wrapped userInfo in any extra layer.
I actually don't have a data layer anywhere.
export async function loginWithGoogle(idToken) {
    try {
        console.log("Sending ID Token:", idToken);
        console.log("Token Length:", idToken.length);

        const data = await request('auth/oauth/google', 'POST', { id_token: idToken });
        console.log("Login with Google response:", data);

        if (data.token) {
            await setToken(data.token);
        }
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Google login error:", error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

I tried the official way and expected the GoogleSignin.signIn() function to return idToken directly on the returned userInfo object, not nested within data. If I destructure data, I can get the idToken but I'm worried about scalability or issues long-term.
So, this works:
const { data: { idToken } } = userInfo;

but unsure if it's something I want to keep long-term.
Here's what the output is:
{
  "data": {
    "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSU...truncated...M5InR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email"
    ],
    "serverAuthCode": "4/0A...truncated...Nh_DCd-3Qi9PVGC87rjn1A",
    "user": {
      "email": "anonymoususer@example.com",
      "familyName": null,
      "givenName": "Anonymous",
      "id": "1111111111111111111111",
      "name": "Anonymous",
      "photo": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AChjS...truncated...=s96-c"
    }
  },
  "type": "success"
}

To be extremely clear, extracting it from the data obj this way works but I just want to make sure it doesn't come bite me back in the bum.
Also, to be clear since AI keeps telling me i'm using expo, I'm not. I don't even know what that is.
